# Using wget to download css with get params

Tags: wget, css

I'm trying to mirror a site but the css linked has the url: `http://127.0.0.1:2368/assets/css/screen.css?v=c44dc08367`

Using wget to download the site saves the css file with the filename `screen.css?v=c44dc08367`

I tried using `--adjust-extension` flag but that saves the file as `screen.css?v=c44dc08367.css` Is it possible to save it the right way as `screen.css` using wget?

I'm using GNU Wget 1.14 built on darwin12.5.0.

EDIT: I can't specify the file name as I'm mirroring the whole site, so the actual command goes like this. The css link is inside the page (which is fetched automatically by wget)

```
wget \
               --recursive \              # follow links to download entire site
               --page-requisites \        # grab everything: css / inlined images
               --no-parent \              # don't go to parent level
               --directory-prefix static \# download contents to static/ folder
               --no-host-directories \    # don't create domain named folder
               --adjust-extension \
               http://127.0.0.1:2368/
```

Comment: Did you resolve this in the end without manual / custom scripts?

Comment: I had the same issue and solved it by using the `httrack` tool. Two more points: did you miss `--convert-links`? And moreover, though `?` is in the filename here, the `?` is replaced with `%3F` in the html source, so it is recognized as being part of the filename.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, wget will make no assumptions about what you want to download unless you tell it to. It doesn't care if your file is an image, a document, a zipped file, et cetera.

The file is saved as whatever the URL ended with – so anything from the last slash to the end of the URL. In your case, that's .css?v=c44dc08367. The part after the actual file extension (.css) is contained in the URL, but it's a HTTP query parameter. For wget, however, it will determine the output filename.

If you want to specify an output filename for wget, add the -O (uppercase O) option:

`wget http://127.0.0.1:2368/assets/css/screen.css?v=c44dc08367 -O screen.css`

Finally, there's the --content-disposition option which might result in the proper filename being set. But this entirely depends on the server you're downloading from sending the correct header information.

Excepts from here: [Why does wget'ing an image give me a file, not an image?](https://superuser.com/questions/457563/why-does-wgeting-an-image-give-me-a-file-not-an-image)

Comment: Thanks Gaurav, but I don't think -O helps in my case. Please refer to the EDIT. Also, I get "screen.css\?v=c44dc08367.css" using --content-disposition which also doesn't help me. Is there any way wget can ignore the query parameter for the filename?

Comment: No I think you can't do that in wget but you can make up a script to do the thing.